# How to convert a string with french accents to an URL (replacing accent letters)?

Tags: regex, clojure

I want to create urls based on strings that automatically convert a string with french accents to a URL.

```
(defn str->url [] ...)
(defn str->url-case [] ...)

(str->url "Élise Noël")
;=> "/elise-noel"
(str->url-case "Élise Noël")
;=> "/Elise-Noel"
```

Here are the non accent letters equivalents :

```
À, Â -> A 
Æ -> AE
Ç -> C
É, È, Ê, Ë -> E
Î, Ï -> I
Ô -> O
Œ -> OE 
Ù, Û, Ü -> U    
Ÿ -> Y

à, â -> a
æ -> ae
ç -> c
é, è, ê, ë -> e
î, ï -> i 
ô -> o
œ -> oe
ù, û, ü -> u
ÿ -> y
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the official URL encoding format (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), which is different from just removing the accents, you can do this:

```
user> (java.net.URLEncoder/encode "Élise Noël" "UTF-8")
"%C3%89lise+No%C3%ABl"
```

To use the replacements from your question, just map `clojure.string/replace` with each of your replacement pairs over the string.

Here's an example for that with just the necessary replacement pairs for the example string. Just follow the same pattern for the rest:

```
(reduce (fn [s [pat repl]]
          (clojure.string/replace s pat repl))
        "Élise Noël"
        [[" " "-"]
         [#"[ÉÈÊË]" "E"]
         [#"[éèêë]" "e"]])
```